# No Json serializer found for type akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse.Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type

Tags: scala, playframework

im using below code in my play controller

```
class MyController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc) {


  val logger: Logger = Logger(this.getClass())

def mypost = Action.async(parse.json) {
  request =>
    val item = request.body.validate[Myrequest]
    val req=request.body.as[Myrequest]
    implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher



        val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io"))


        responseFuture.map {
          case response @ HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, _, _, _) =>
            val setCookies = response.headers
            println(s"Cookies set by a server: $setCookies")
            Ok(Json.toJson(response))
          case _ => sys.error("something wrong")
        }




}
}
```

Getting below error when invoking this controller

```
No Json serializer found for type akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

I have tried returning response body in Json instead of whole HttpResponse as below

```
Ok(Json.toJson(response.entity.dataBytes.runWith(Sink.fold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ )).map(.utf8String) map { result => Json.parse(result) }))
```

it throws error

```
"No Json serializer found for type scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type. " –
```

Or should i use any other HttpClient?

Comment: I think you want `Ok(Json.parse(response.body))` (maybe even without the parse) or something similar.

Comment: You also don't want to start a new Actor system for every request. Better use the one you are already injecting instead.

Comment: This error occurs when Play doesn’t know how to turn something into JSON by default (for example, turning a case class containing a custom class into JSON will throw this error if you haven’t also defined how you want that custom class to look as JSON). You haven’t defined how to turn a HttpResponse into JSON and it doesn’t know how to do that automatically, so you’ll probably need to either just parse the `response.body`, or define how you want a HttpResponse to look when it’s in JSON format.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley how to return Json response body from HttpResponse?

Comment: @Thilo can you please elaborate more on "use the one you are already injecting instead", and how to inject the same Actor system for everyrequest? and also why shouldn"t i create new Actor system for every request

Comment: @Thilo Do i really need actorSystem in this controller?

Comment: You should not create a new actor system for every request, because this is rather heavy. Usually you create these for the whole lifetime of your application. Do you need an actorSystem? I don't know, but you have set up an `implicit` for it. Maybe `Http()` wants to have it?

Comment: @Thilo i do have singleton on top of Controller class,if thats what you think is missing ,if not please lemme know the code snippet to reuse Actor system for every request

Comment: Yes, use the singleton on top instead of making a new instance. Just delete the three lines about that. May need to make it an implicit or pass it explicitly to whatever needs it.

Comment: @Thilo can you please be more specific ..maybe a code snippet

Comment: `implicit val system = actorSystem` instead of the three lines you now have.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error message says, if you want to put the entire `HttpResponse` object in the body you need to define a [Writes](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Writes) for it.

If you only want to pass on the response body, and the response body is something that already has a Writes defined e.g. Json (`JsValue`) or `String`, then you can just extract that from the `HttpResponse` and return that e.g. `Ok(responseBody)`

Comment: how to extract responsebody from HttpResponse? I have tried    Ok(Json.toJson(response.entity.dataBytes.runWith(Sink.fold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _)).map(_.utf8String) map { result =>
              Json.parse(result)
            })) . it throws me error "No Json serializer found for type scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
"

Comment: That code tries to serialize a `Future[JsValue]` as Json. Try `response.entity.dataBytes.runWith(...).map(result => Ok( Json.parse(result)))`, where `...` means the code you alread have for extracting a string.